# How can I take a screenshot of a complete PDF file?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a PDF file that has three pages.

How could I combine the three pages into one single screenshot?

Comment: You could just take several screen shots and cut and paste them into one image.

Comment: I believe [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) could do that – at least in version 9.

Comment: Snagit is your best bet. Should you need to stitch them together on your own, try Microsoft ICE http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/ice/

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 natively has "Snipping tool" (under accessoires) that you can use to gather each page (or section of page) and then paste with paint to a new image. Each "New image" automatically puts it in the paste buffer.
You could also print the selected pages to a new PDF, if you have configured a generic PDF printer.

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button (usually between the letter and numeric keys) on the page you want to take a screenshot. Then open Microsoft Paint or other image editing program and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste).

Proceed similarly with other pages.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. this won't capture the long pages. it only captures what you are seeing on the screen