# Adobe acrobat PDFs into TIFF

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a couple of PDFs that I want to merge into a single tiff file. I can get acrobat to combine the files but it exports as one tiff file per page. Is there a setting to get it to export as a single tiff?

Comment: If you don't find a suitable answer you may have a look at [PDF-Xchange Viewer.](http://superuser.com/questions/452092/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-complete-pdf-file/536060#536060)

Comment: @nixda thanks, that does get me a single tiff, but it adds an extra step to the process as I have to first combine to single PDF in acrobat then export with PDF-Xchange, it would b great to find a solution that uses acrobat